# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg apache commons validator routines UrlValidator exception when upgrading common-validator from 1.4.0 to 1.6

Tags: java, tomcat8, jersey-2.0

I work on the url shortener project. To test the validation of a url, I use the common-validator version 1.4.0. I use jersey and my web server is tomcat. After upgrading common-validator to version 1.6, I get the following exception. Could anybody help me?

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] threw exception</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg&#47;apache&#47;commons&#47;validator&#47;routines&#47;UrlValidator;
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:308)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:210)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:137)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:776)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:464)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:183)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:349)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:339)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1136)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:308)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:210)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:137)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:776)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:464)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:183)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:349)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:339)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.31</h3></body></html>
```

I only get this exception when I use tomcat.

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fanapium.tinylink</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinylink</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>tinylink</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <jersey2.version>2.19</jersey2.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hashids</groupId>
            <artifactId>hashids</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.floragunn</groupId>
            <artifactId>search-guard-ssl</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0-19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fanapium.keylead</groupId>
            <artifactId>keylead-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/TinyLink</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/TinyLink/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.fanapium.tinylink.TinyLinkServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>

                    <finalName>TinyLink/tinylink</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: shouldn't be an issue since there is no significant change from 1.4 to 1.6, also class is present: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/index.html, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/changes-report.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your `commons-validator.jar` exists in your war file. The class [still exists](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) in 1.6 and no dependencies have been changed since version 1.4. See the [release notes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/changes-report.html).

Comment: Thank you.
My problem was solved after adding the common-validator to the artifact and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the class `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator` is missing in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by adding the jar files in the path : C:\Jboss_Seam\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\default\lib